# How to access field of last element of sub array in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having an array (json object converted to array) like

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"5ab8d6faff24ae1204000862"
      },
      "allotment_details":[
         {
            "allotment_id":"468986c5-2155-01e9-74cb-3ad05c66800d",
            "hostel_id":{
               "$oid":"5ae69fb4d2ccda0e70005551"
            },
            "room_id":"ca62d5b5-8fac-62c4-9e62-7e7b9ce9a714",
            "food_preference":"Vegetarian",
            "from_date":{
               "$date":{
                  "$numberLong":"1527372000000"
               }
            },
            "to_date":{
               "$date":{
                  "$numberLong":"1528063200000"
               }
            },
            "approved_by":{
               "$oid":"5af2bda9bc1e370f9c0036d9"
            },
            "date_of_allotment":{
               "$date":{
                  "$numberLong":"1529487464000"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "allotment_id":"c17043a4-7b5b-a132-8226-a4594b61658d",
            "hostel_id":{
               "$oid":"5ae69fb4d2ccda0e70005551"
            },
            "room_id":"ca62d5b5-8fac-62c4-9e62-7e7b9ce9a714",
            "food_preference":"Vegetarian",
            "from_date":{
               "$date":{
                  "$numberLong":"1527372000000"
               }
            },
            "to_date":{
               "$date":{
                  "$numberLong":"1530223200000"
               }
            },
            "approved_by":{
               "$oid":"5af2bda9bc1e370f9c0036d9"
            },
            "date_of_allotment":{
               "$date":{
                  "$numberLong":"1529571140000"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am trying to tweak the below lines of code

```
var allotmentDetailsArray = data[0]['allotment_details'];
if (typeof allotmentDetailsArray != 'undefined')
{  
    if(allotmentDetailsArray.length == 0)
    {
        isStudentValidForAllotment =true;            
    }
    else
    {
        //traverse
        var to_date_of_last_sub_array= data[0]["allotment_details"][lastIndex]["to_date"];
    }
}
```

I want to get the value of "to_date" in the last element of allotment_details sub array... Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line

```
var to_date_of_last_sub_array= data[0]["allotment_details"][lastIndex]["to_date"];
```

to this:

```
var to_date_of_last_sub_array= data[0]["allotment_details"][(data[0]["allotment_details"].length - 1)]["to_date"];
```

[MDN Array.length documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: Will be more cleaner to access object properties using [Dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation): `data[0].allotment_details[data[0].allotment_details.length - 1].to_date`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I agree, but I always want to stick as close to the original code so the poster can spot exactly where he or she should change the code. That's why I left it that way, but you are totally right!

Answer (score 3):

To get the last element of an array you can use `pop()`, or `slice(-1).pop()` to clone the array before retrieval so the element is not removed. From there you can just access each property by name. Try this:

```js
var data = [{
  "allotment_details": [{
    "to_date": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1528063200000"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "to_date": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1530223200000"
      }
    }
  }]
}]

var date = data[0].allotment_details.slice(-1).pop().to_date.$date.$numberLong;
console.log(date);
```

Note that I removed the irrelevant properties from the object you provided to make the answer more succinct.

Comment: Good answer, but no need to call `slice(-1)`

Comment: Thanks, although I explained that in the answer. I used it for safety as I don't know what the OP is doing with that array after this logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const data = [{"_id":{"$oid":"5ab8d6faff24ae1204000862"},"allotment_details":[{"allotment_id":"468986c5-2155-01e9-74cb-3ad05c66800d","hostel_id":{"$oid":"5ae69fb4d2ccda0e70005551"},"room_id":"ca62d5b5-8fac-62c4-9e62-7e7b9ce9a714","food_preference":"Vegetarian","from_date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1527372000000"}},"to_date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1528063200000"}},"approved_by":{"$oid":"5af2bda9bc1e370f9c0036d9"},"date_of_allotment":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1529487464000"}}},{"allotment_id":"c17043a4-7b5b-a132-8226-a4594b61658d","hostel_id":{"$oid":"5ae69fb4d2ccda0e70005551"},"room_id":"ca62d5b5-8fac-62c4-9e62-7e7b9ce9a714","food_preference":"Vegetarian","from_date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1527372000000"}},"to_date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1530223200000"}},"approved_by":{"$oid":"5af2bda9bc1e370f9c0036d9"},"date_of_allotment":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1529571140000"}}}]}];
const toDate = data[0].allotment_details[data[0].allotment_details.length - 1].to_date;

console.log(toDate);
```